# Calculate the % for a Row in a Table Where the Values are Strings in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I'm trying to get a report in Looker Studio in a table where it is showing me the percentage of the different Status for a region. The items in the Status field are strings.

When I use a normal pivot table I get the following which looks to be doing the calculation on the whole table instead of just a region:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I filter to just one region I get the following data which is the correct calculation I'm looking for but I need it to do this for all regions:

[image]